# SQL Error [53100]: could not write to file « base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp8524.111 » : No space left on device

Tags: linux, postgresql, talend

can i please get some assistance: why i am receiving this error and how can i fix this ?

> ERROR: could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp8524.111": No
> space left on device SQL state: 53100

i have 150 GB free space on my local disk and i still got this error that says " no space left on device SQL State: 53100".

I got this error on PGAdmin 4 version 6.9. PostgreSQL 12

also i got the above error when i run the following query :

```
INSERT INTO  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_ODS"."DIM_CAT_NAF_ENTR_TMP" (
    "ID_SIREN", 
    "ID_NIC",
    "CD_DS_CAT_JURI_NIV1_ENTR",
    "CD_DS_CAT_JURI_NIV2_ENTR",
    "CD_DS_CAT_JURI_NIV4_ENTR",
    "CD_DS_SEC_NAF_ENTR",
    "CD_DS_DIVISION_NAF_ENTR",
    "CD_DS_ACT_PRIN_ENTR"
    )
SELECT
ENTR."ID_SIREN" AS ID_SIREN,
ETAB."ID_NIC" AS ID_NIC,
CASE WHEN CJUR3."CD_CAT_NIV1"='' OR CJUR3."CD_CAT_NIV1" IS NULL THEN 'ZZ - Non renseignée' ELSE CONCAT(replace(CJUR3."CD_CAT_NIV1", ' ', ''), ' - ', CJUR3."DS_CAT_NIV1") END AS CD_DS_CAT_JURI_NIV1_ENTR,
CASE WHEN CJUR2."CD_CAT_NIV2"='' OR CJUR2."CD_CAT_NIV2" IS NULL THEN 'ZZ - Non renseignée' ELSE CONCAT(replace(CJUR2."CD_CAT_NIV2", ' ', ''), ' - ', CJUR2."DS_CAT_NIV2") END AS CD_DS_CAT_JURI_NIV2_ENTR,
CASE WHEN CJUR1."CD_CAT_NIV4"='' OR CJUR1."CD_CAT_NIV4" IS NULL THEN 'ZZ - Non renseignée' ELSE CONCAT(replace(CJUR1."CD_CAT_NIV4", ' ', ''), ' - ', CJUR1."DS_CAT_NIV4") END AS CD_DS_CAT_JURI_NIV4_ENTR,
CASE WHEN RSE_ENTR3."CD_SECTION_NAF"='' OR RSE_ENTR3."CD_SECTION_NAF" IS NULL THEN 'ZZ - Non renseignée' ELSE CONCAT(RSE_ENTR3."CD_SECTION_NAF", ' - ', RSE_ENTR3."DS_SECTION_NAF") END AS CD_DS_NAF1_ENTR,
CASE WHEN RSE_ENTR1."CD_DIVISION_NAF"='' OR RSE_ENTR1."CD_DIVISION_NAF" IS NULL THEN 'ZZ - Non renseignée' ELSE CONCAT(RSE_ENTR1."CD_DIVISION_NAF", ' - ',  RSE_ENTR1."DS_DIVISION_NAF") END AS CD_DS_NAF2_ENTR,
CASE WHEN RSE_ENTR2."CD_ACT_PRIN_ENTR"='' OR RSE_ENTR2."CD_ACT_PRIN_ENTR" IS NULL THEN 'ZZ - Non renseignée' ELSE CONCAT(RSE_ENTR2."CD_ACT_PRIN_ENTR", ' - ',  RSE_ENTR2."DS_ACT_PRIN_ENTR") END AS CD_DS_NAF4_ENTR


FROM  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_ODS"."SR_ETAB" ETAB
INNER JOIN "SIRENE"."SIRENE_ODS"."SR_ENTR" ENTR ON (ETAB."ID_SIREN" = ENTR."ID_SIREN")
LEFT JOIN  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_REF"."REF_ACT_NAF_ENTR" RSE_ENTR1 ON (SUBSTR(ENTR."CD_NAF4_ENTR",1,2) = RSE_ENTR1."CD_DIVISION_NAF")
LEFT JOIN  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_REF"."REF_CAT_JUR_ENTR" CJUR1 ON (ENTR."CD_CAT_NIV4_ENTR" = CJUR1."CD_CAT_NIV4")
LEFT JOIN  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_REF"."REF_ACT_NAF_ENTR" RSE_ENTR2 ON (ENTR."CD_NAF4_ENTR" = RSE_ENTR2."CD_ACT_PRIN_ENTR")
LEFT JOIN  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_REF"."REF_CAT_JUR_ENTR" CJUR2 ON (SUBSTR(ENTR."CD_CAT_NIV4_ENTR",1,2) = CJUR2."CD_CAT_NIV2")
LEFT JOIN  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_REF"."REF_ACT_NAF_ENTR" RSE_ENTR3 ON (ENTR."CD_NAF_NIV1" = RSE_ENTR3."CD_SECTION_NAF")
LEFT JOIN  "SIRENE"."SIRENE_REF"."REF_CAT_JUR_ENTR" CJUR3 ON (SUBSTR(ENTR."CD_CAT_NIV4_ENTR",1,1) = CJUR3."CD_CAT_NIV1")
```

This query is supposed to insert 24 million row in a new table but it took just 11 minutes to run on my friend machine. but for me it took more than 4 hours ant it end with the error : SQL Error [53100]: could not write to file « base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp8524.111 » : No space left on device.

And this happened despite the optimizing of postgresql performance !!!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That looks like PostgreSQL is creating temporary files for e.g. sorting/joining and that is using up your disk space. Without knowing more about your schema, setup, operating system it isn't possible to say much more. Start by running just the SELECT part of your query + seeing how many rows that returns - maybe it is many more rows than you are expecting

Comment: I guess once the query fails it removes the temp files so you'll have plenty of storage.

Collect statistics by running analyze on all of your tables in that query. (Could result in a different execution plan.)
There's a nice tool I recommend: https://explain.depesz.com/